# NSDateFormatter difference

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

What is the difference between these two Date Formats. First one give actual time but second on give time buy adding time zone offset value.

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
NSDate *dateConverted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-12-02T12:15:43.182Z"];
NSLog(@"Date: %@",dateConverted); //
```

Date: **2013-12-02 12:15:43 +0000**

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSS'Z'"];
NSDate *dateConverted1 = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:@"2013-12-02T12:15:43.182Z"];
NSLog(@"%@",dateConverted1);
```

Date: **2013-12-02 06:45:43 +0000**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the 2nd format is all of the needless quotes, especially around the `Z`. By quoting the `Z` this means the `Z` is treated as a literal character and not the timezone format specifier.

Get rid of the quotes around the `Z` and both will give the same result.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. In a date formatter, any characters inside of quotes are treated as literal characters and not format specifiers.

Comment: Then what is 'T' their? It should also treated as literal character.

Comment: You want the `T` in quotes because that is an actual literal in the string that must be treated as an actual literal and not interpreted as anything special. The `Z` in the string is special, it is a timezone. So the format can't have the `Z` in quotes but the `T` must be in quotes.

Comment: Here I have doubt, If I write 'Z' then date formatter will not treated it as a timezone ? please clarify me.

Comment: Correct. If the date format has `'Z'` then the `Z` in the date string is treated as the literal string `Z` and not as the Zulu timezone.

Answer (score 2):

The second date formatter is incorrect, the 'Z' should not be single quoted, that keeps it from being considered a format character.

Also the only single quotes that are needed are around the 'T' so that is is not considered a format character but rather a literal.

See ICU User Guide: [Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)

Comment: Thanks, this link is very informative about date format behaviour.